# webauthn não funcionando

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Estou tentando usar (e aprendendo) o webauthn no meu site, mas o método de autenticação "platform" não funciona, retornando o erro DOMException: The operation either timed out or was not allowed.

Quando troco o método para "cross-platform", funciona.

Meu código:

```
let credential = navigator.credentials.create({
  publicKey: {
    challenge: Uint8Array.from(
      "3bn83gh8negn8hs8",
      c => c.charCodeAt(0)
    ),
    rp: {
      name: "nome do site ",
      id: "url do site",
    },
    user: {
      id: Uint8Array.from(
        "UZSL85T9AFC",
        c => c.charCodeAt(0)
      ),
      name: "email",
      displayName: "nome",
    },
    pubKeyCredParams: [{
      alg: -7,
      type: "public-key"
    }],
    authenticatorSelection: {
      authenticatorAttachment: "platform",
      userVerification: "preferred"
    },
    timeout: 30000,
    attestation: "direct"
  }
});
```

Eu uso o Edge 87.0.664.24

Answer (score 0):

Descobri no site https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/windows-integration/web-authentication que o Windows Hello usa o algoritmo RS256.

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
pubKeyCredParams: [{
  alg: -257,
  type: "public-key"
}]
```